# python: install package to custom python environment

Tags: python, conda

i am using a python script that uses custom python enviroment defined at the begining of the script:

```
!/home/gleb/amber22//miniconda/bin/python
```

when I run this python script it produces the following error:

```
 version or install mpi4py.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gleb/amber22/bin/MMPBSA.py.MPI", line 53, in <module>
    from mpi4py import MPI
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpi4py'
```

I've already installed mpi4py using anaconda in the python3

```
conda install -c conda-forge mpi4py
```

how could I install mpi4py to
!/home/gleb/amber22//miniconda/bin/python
?

Comment: From your other question, it seems that you have both anaconda and miniconda installed. In your other question, you installed mpi4py to anaconda. I would suggest you delete anaconda, remove references to it from your bashrc and only keep miniconda. So that when you do `conda install` it will isntall to miniconda

Comment: There is no need to have both of them. It only creates confusion (best evidence is this question)

Comment: yep that's right! and it's not possible to install package selecting miniconda ?? ;-) becasue this miniconda was created by specific program (which I try to run)

Comment: Try doing `conda deactivate` followed by `source /home/gleb/amber22//miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh` Then do `conda install -c conda-forge mpi4py`

Comment: it installed packages but the python script still does not work with the same error.. it seems to me that I will have to reinstall it since during installation it takes something from my anaconda enviroment to its own miniconda

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying the ***target*** feature in pip.

```
pip install "package_name" -t "directory"
```

or try:

```
pip install mylibraryName -t "!/home/gleb/amber22//miniconda/bin/python"
```

but you are using Anaconda so if you have the normal python installed and if you can type **PIP** commands in your terminal/command prompt then these commands can work, By the way, Anaconda installs modules the same way as PIP does (the files, etc.).